# Cannot access field on a value with type ARRAY

Tags: array, string, query, select, bigquery

Estou tentando puxar a coluna `name.pt_BR` que está dentro da coluna `name`porém ainda não entendi como pegar especificamente ela no Bigquery.

Como puxar essa info pra dar JOIN em outra query depois?

```
SELECT name.pt_BR FROM `source_internal.skills`
```

Retorna o erro

> Cannot access field pt_BR on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<pt_BR
> STRING, en STRING>> at [1:13]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. Basta [aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) a resposta que resolveu o problema, isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido. Ou, caso não tenha sido a resposta abaixo que resolveu, vc mesma pode responder: basta usar o campo de respostas abaixo (o textarea "Sua Resposta"), e depois marque-a como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar o comando [**UNNEST**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays).

No seu exemplo acho que ficaria algo como:

```
SELECT n.pt_BR FROM `source_internal.skills`, UNNEST(name) AS n
```